# Adding onClick method with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a ready library written in jquery code in the project. However, I would like to add a custom one onClick = test () {} method. However, the method I added with JavaScript is not included in the button.I can't see my method inside the button. What should I do

```
var s = v("<div></div>")
                  .addClass("toolbar toolbar-" + t)
                  .attr("role", "toolbar"),
                e =
                  !1 !== this.options.toolbarSettings.showNextButton
                    ? v("<button></button>")
                        .text(this.options.lang.next)
                        .addClass("btn sw-btn-next")
                        .attr("type", "button")
                        .on("click", function test(){}) // <<<---- The onclick method I want to add to the button
                    : null,
```

Comment: How do you know its not working? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: then I want to keep the method ready to make changes on the page.

Comment: "then I want to keep the method ready to make changes on the page." I have no clue what that means. You are not going to see an event handler as an attribute when you inspect it. It does not mean it was not added. Add some code and click it, watch it be called.

Comment: I understood thank you for your help @epascarello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see all your code, but I try repeat it in playground. 
Please see part of it:

```
const v = (element) => {
  return $('#main').append(element)
}
var s = v("<button></button>")
  .text('test')
  .addClass("btn sw-btn-next")
  .attr("type", "button")
  .on("click", function test(){ console.log('test')})
```

In playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/4d1ewt6v/7/